# Can IntelliJ IDEA show list of all violations of Nullable annotation

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is there option in IntelliJ IDEA to show list of all java source files where variable or return value of method annotated with @Nullable is used in a code?

For example, if I want to improve and update all source files with such violations I would like to see list all files (otherwise I have to open each single source and visually inspect highlighted areas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to find probable problems/bugs by running a single inspection, via

```
Analyze > Run inspection by name
```

You might then customize the inspection settings for the single execution.

[image]

Those are the inspections you're looking for, most probably.

[image]

Running the inspection "Constant conditions & exceptions returns

[image]

Btw, I'm an inspections maniac for these kind of things, glad to see others do so ;)

Comment: LppEdd thank you! This helped me to find way to run inspection. Still I have problem with your advice. Maybe you have experience and can tell me what I did wrong. If I do that way I get no any reports. If I run Analyse/Inspect code I get report on all Nullable. I would rather use Run inspection by name to speed up analyze.

Comment: @igor.beslic I will try that again on a project asap and let you know. In the meantime, check the scope you choosed

Comment: @igor.beslic See last edit. The result you want to have is obtained via the inspection "Constant conditions & exceptions". Just run a sample on my project and it works nicely.

Comment: Yes, now with right inspection name I can run it with keyboard shortcut. Thank you!